# How do I sort a wordlist by string length?

Tags: text-processing

There is a wordlist look like this;

```
123
b
1
4rr
f
k3j3
gg
```

Then I needed to sort these words by string length (doesn't matter which start with numeric or string both are okay)

The output should be this:

```
b
1
f
gg
123
4rr
4rr
```

Is there a sort command that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to do this on the command-line.

Most command line tools work in a line-based manner, so it is straightforward with `awk`, `sort` and `cut`, see for example [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917576/sort-a-text-file-by-line-length-including-spaces):

```sh
awk '{ print length, $0 }' testfile | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
```

Breakdown:

```sh
# Print line-length and the line
awk '{ print length, $0 }' testfile |

# Sort numerically by line-length
sort -n |

# Remove line-length number
cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Output:

```
1
b
f
gg
123
4rr
k3j3
```

See `man awk`, `info sort` and `info cut` for more.

Comment: Sort those who are searching and want to reverse the result, just all `-r` to the `sort` command